# In SVG, why the stroke are blurry in some specific positions

Tags: html, svg

I just use SVG to draw rectangles, but I found the stroke were blurry when the position 'x' is an integer while others were not when the position 'x' is an integer plus 0.5

It can be reproduced both in Chrome and IE, has someone met this before?

```html
<svg type="svg-chart" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px;">
    <g>
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="17" height="81" style="fill:rgb(31,119,180);fill-opacity:0.7019607843137254;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-opacity:1" class="gm-shape-grid-bar" type="shape" subtype="gbar" status="normal"></rect>
        <rect x="23" y="2" width="17.5" height="81" style="fill:rgb(31,119,180);fill-opacity:0.7019607843137254;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-opacity:1" class="gm-shape-grid-bar" type="shape" subtype="gbar" status="normal"></rect>
        <rect x="43.5" y="2" width="19.5" height="81" style="fill:rgb(31,119,180);fill-opacity:0.7019607843137254;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-opacity:1" class="gm-shape-grid-bar" type="shape" subtype="gbar"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding lines between adjecent svg rectangles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376308/avoiding-lines-between-adjecent-svg-rectangles)

Comment: yes, one way I can adjust coordinate according to the stroke(border),
another way can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty