# Edge / corner color issues with SVG line / path

Tags: svg

This:

```html
<svg width=100 height=100>
  <g transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)" stroke=red fill=none>
    <line x1=10 y1=10 x2=10 y2=50 />
    <path d="M20,10 H20 V50 H20 Z" />
    <path d="M30,10 H31 V50 H30 Z" />
    <path d="M40,10 H42 V50 H40 Z" />
    <path d="M50,10 H52 V50 H50 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

produces image like this in Chrome (zoomed in so it's obvious):

Top part

[image]

Bottom part

[image]

Note that the edges of the lines and the corners of the rectangles are of a slightly lighter red.

This looks like it's anti-aliasing, but trying `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34229584/3821009) did not fully work. The problem is that it then cuts the line by 1px instead:

```html
<svg width=100 height=100>
  <g shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke=red fill=none>
    <line x1=10 y1=10 x2=10 y2=50 />
    <path d="M20,10 H20 V50 H20 Z" />
    <path d="M30,10 H31 V50 H30 Z" />
    <path d="M40,10 H42 V50 H40 Z" />
    <path d="M50,10 H52 V50 H50 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Top part

[image]

Bottom part

[image]

Is there a way to fix this somehow, so I get the same line color across the specified coordinate range?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Win10/64/Chrome 101

Comment: @MichaelMullany Interesting, because I'm also on Win10/64/Chrome 101. I'm pretty sure I can see the inconsistency on my smartphone when I zoom in (it's not big enough zoom for me to be 100% certain), though the effects seem to be different - now in both examples it seems to be cutting the line from both ends instead of aliasing.

Comment: Might be a graphics card specific issue?

Comment: @MichaelMullany Perhaps, but that wouldn't explain the smartphone exhibiting similar behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Win64 Chrome, I'm only seeing the antialiasing on the first two elements.

The explanation for the line element is simple.  Because you are translating down by half a pixel, the two line ends are ending halfway up/down a pixel.  Hence you will get antialiasing in that case.  Adjust the coords, or add `stroke-linecap="square"` to fix that.

*Illustration:*

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 70 40" width="420">
  <g transform="translate(10,10)">
    <g fill="none" stroke="#ccc" id="grid">
      <rect width="10" height="10"/>
      <rect x="10" width="10" height="10"/>
      <rect y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/>
    </g>

    <!-- line (as is) -->
    <line x1="5" y1="20" x2="5" y2="5" stroke="#00c8" stroke-width="10"/>
    <line x1="5" y1="20" x2="5" y2="5" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(40,10)">
    <use xlink:href="#grid"/>

    <!-- rectamngle corner -->
    <path d="M 5,20 L 5,5 L 20,5" fill="none" stroke="#00c8" stroke-width="10"/>
    <path d="M 5,20 L 5,5 L 20,5" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1"/>
  </g>


</svg>
```

As for the zero width rectangle. Not sure what's happening there. It is only slightly lighter.  It is likely a rendering bug in Skia.  It may only effect the GPU renderer of Skia (I didn't check). The GPU renderer has a few more rendering bugs on these sort of edge cases than the CPU rendering path.  If you care, you could [file a bug about it](https://crbug.com).

```html
<svg width=100 height=100>
  <g transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)" stroke=red fill=none>
    <line x1=10 y1=10 x2=10 y2=50 stroke-linecap="square"/>
    <path d="M20,10 H20 V50 H20 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! "Because you are translating down by half a pixel, the two line ends are ending halfway up/down a pixel." I don't get this - why doesn't this apply to paths as well? Isn't the svg "in-between" pixels anyway? I.e. a horizontal line in svg with y=0.5 should be fully on "physical pixel" y=1, right? At least that's what I gathered from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34229584/3821009) I linked to (and the link inside it as well). "It is only slightly lighter." My hunch is that it's because rectangle has both horizontal and vertical lines, which add up.

Comment: It only applies to the line because the line ends there (at the half pixel).  But in the case of the rectangles, they turn the corner and keep going.  So the rest of that corner pixel gets drawn.

Comment: I added an illustration to show what I mean in case it isn't clear.